# ufw won't allow connections to postgres port 5432

Tags: firewall, postgresql, telnet, ufw, port

With `ufw disable` on remote postgres system i'm able to connect from my local system

However, the connection does not work when I `ufw enable` as shown below:

```
C:\Users\HOME>telnet 80.240.24.195 5432
Connecting To 80.240.24.195...Could not open connection to the host, on port 5432: Connect failed
```

Below is my postgres configuration at the time of restart.

cat /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
```

cat /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

telnet works when tried from the postgres host itself, but then I try to make the connection from my local laptop it fails.

```
root@DKERP:/# ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 8069                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] 443/tcp                    DENY IN     Anywhere
[ 4] 443                        DENY IN     Anywhere
[ 5] 80/tcp                     DENY IN     Anywhere
[ 6] 80,443,5432/tcp            DENY IN     Anywhere
[ 7] 80                         DENY IN     Anywhere
[ 8] 4433/tcp                   DENY IN     Anywhere
[ 9] 5432/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[10] 22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[11] 8069 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[12] 443/tcp (v6)               DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
[13] 443 (v6)                   DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
[14] 80/tcp (v6)                DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
[15] 80,443,5432/tcp (v6)       DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
[16] 80 (v6)                    DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
[17] 4433/tcp (v6)              DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
[18] 5432/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Can you please suggest what needs to be further done to get the postgres to connect to work from my local laptop?

Comment: What doesn't work? Include any error messages.

Comment: @NasirRiley updated the error message: `C:\Users\HOME>telnet 80.240.24.195 5432
Connecting To 80.240.24.195...Could not open connection to the host, on port 5432: Connect failed`

Answer (score 0):

There as an entry in `ufw` that was denying port 5432 as seen in the output. i deleted that entry and restarted the service to make this work.

```
[ 6] 80,443,5432/tcp            DENY IN     Anywhere

 ufw delete 6

ufw disable

ufw enable
```